# Converting HTML to doc(x) and / or PDF

Tags: html, pdf, docx, doc, aspose

I have to convert html to the doc(x) and pdf format.

I found aspose, but this tool can do a lot of more work than i need, and thats why it isn't really cheap.

Are there similar tools, which can just do this conversion ?

I need this on a Desktopapplication where no word / office is installed

**Just for Info Finally bought asponse words. all other options weren't as good as this tool*

Comment: Is the html from your webserver, or do you just have the file?

Comment: It's stored in a database. They were imported E-Mail messages

Comment: [VsWord](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/8991-PHP-Create-DOCX-Word-document-dynamically-from-HTML.html) is a package created by Raskin Veniamin which allows you to dynamically create files DOCX simply by converting HTML to .DOCX. - http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/315-Create-Microsoft-Word-DOCX-files-from-HTML-in-PHP-Part-1-Simple-Example.html

Comment: https://pandoc.org/ can do this, and is free and open-source.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that these are essentially “documents” and not fancy graphical web pages (i.e. you'd like them to be legible, but aren't deeply concerned with the minutiæ of web layout formatting), you can use LibreOffice to convert them; either manually (open, export as…) or using the "headless" mode, e.g.:

```
soffice -headless -convert-to pdf -outdir pdfs/ *.html
soffice -headless -convert-to doc -outdir docs/ *.html
```

Free, cross-platform, but a bit of a hefty install. (I think it's nearing the half-gigabyte mark for the full suite with all the plug-ins installed, but you should only need the Writer component)

Comment: If you did want to convert "fancy graphical pages" you could use GrabzIt's HTML to DOCX API: https://grabz.it/html-to-word-docx-api.aspx

It uses a browser to ensure it renders properly.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this http://kitpdf.com might help. I tried it, it's free and really easy to use.

Comment: This website is not working anymore or is not giving the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ABCPdf:

http://www.websupergoo.com/products.htm

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for docx format, but you might look into DocRaptor to [convert HTML to PDF](http://docraptor.com/) format. It definitely handles CSS styling better than comparable programs, and doesn't just give you an image like creating a PDF with Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

If the webpage is or can be hosted then you can download an extension for Google Chrome called Screen Capture, this allows you to take a full screen grab of the webpage then you can paste it into Photoshop and Save As a .pdf (that is assuming you have Photoshop that is)

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that i have a desktop application (Winform / WPF) and now office is installed

Comment: That gives you a PDF with a picture in it, not a PDF with words in it. That may be acceptable to Boas but it's worth pointing out the difference.